# OpenXML Tag Formatting

Tags: python, lxml, openxml, elementtree

I am attempting to parse Open XML from a Microsoft Word document. However, whenever i go to look at any tag or attribute i receive the tag i want, preceded by the openxmlformats namespace. Examples below. Does anybody know how i can remove this, and only receive my tag id and value?

**Current format:**

```
for content in root.iter():
    print(content.tag)
```

returns:

```
'{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}tag'
```

and

```
for content in root.iter('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}tag'):
    print(content.attrib)
```

returns

```
 '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}val': 'Orange'
```

**Desired Output:**

```
for content in root.iter():
    print(content.tag)
```

returns

```
tag
```

and

```
for content in root.iter('tag'):
    print(content.attrib)
```

returns

```
 val : 'Orange'
```

Comment: Add a wrapper function that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own version of the iterator that does what you want:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re

my_content = namedtuple('my_content', ['tag', 'attrib'])

def remove_namespace(name):
    return re.sub('^\{[^\}]\}', '', name)

def my_iterator(root, tag=None, namespace='{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'):
    iterator = root.iter() if tag is None else root.iter(namespace + tag)
    for content in iterator:
        tag = remove_namespace(content.tag)
        attrib = {remove_namespace(key): val for key, val in content.attrib.items()}
        yield my_content(tag, attrib)
```

This will return objects that only have the `tag` and `attrib` attributes. You will have to write a more complex proxy object if you want more detailed functionality. You can use the generator as a replacement for the previous:

```
for content in my_iter(root):
    print(content.tag)
```

and

```
for content in my_iter(root, 'tag'):
    print(content.attrib)
```